# How do I move a view within a viewgroup (android)?

Tags: android, drag, touch-event

I'm having trouble dragging/moving views within a view group.

In my root Activity I have a linear layout that adds two custom views - PaintAreaView and PaletteView. Within my PaletteView class (which extends ViewGroup) I am adding several of a third view, PaintView. The PaletteView arranges the PaintViews in a custom layout. I need to be able to drag the PaintViews around the PaletteView, but I have not been able to utilize any drag or move tutorials I've found successfully with my App. I'm new to all this so maybe there's something fundamental that I'm missing. It feels like such a simple thing so I assume I'm missing something very obvious, but any help will be very welcome!

Currently I'm trying to implement the movability through the PaintView class as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    final int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            // Save the ID of this pointer
            mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
            final int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            mPosX += dx;
            mPosY += dy;

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            invalidate();
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        {
            final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId)
            {
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Everything I had tried had failed, so as a base I borrowed this from a tutorial which worked great when moving a single view. But even it doesn't work for me. To post all the code would be too much, but if any additional code would be helpful, let me know.

Is this the wrong way to go about it? Should I be trying to implement the movability through the PaletteView in which the PaintViews are added instead of within the PaintView itself (which technically I have tried)? Is it potentially a problem caused by having a custom layout in PaletteView? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be adding dragging listener to the individual view that you want to move around (ex: the paintviews). I am not sure the exact problem you are facing. It would be good to show the results from the dragging effect to see where the problem is

Source for drag and drop: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html